# One thread for each mob in a 2D game: Will it be system-resource consuming?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm developing a java 2D game, with a Board class and Mob(s) class. The board class has a thread that calls 'repaint()' every a specified delay, while the mobs class constructs a new thread for each of the mob spawned, which means when it does something, it ticks its time on its own. Simply said, I seperate the thread to enable frame rate setting. So i just need to only set how long does the Board thread sleep, like faster sleep means more frame rate (I use threads for this because a site says threaded timing can be made real precise). But then it means in a crowded in-game situation there would be a lot of thread running from every active Mob there.

My question: if i have this lots of thread running at the same time, wouldn't it be consuming a lot of system resources? And if yes, what is the best way round so I don't need to use threads? (just to note 2D game "crowded" situation can be "really crowded").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question could resume to one of these :

[Why is creating a Thread said to be expensive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483047/why-is-creating-a-thread-said-to-be-expensive)

[How expensive is creating of a new thread in Java? When should we consider using of a thread pool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195035/how-expensive-is-creating-of-a-new-thread-in-java-when-should-we-consider-using)

[Is it expensive to create the Thread object or to actually start the thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14569457/is-it-expensive-to-create-the-thread-object-or-to-actually-start-the-thread)

etc...

Plenty of resource to find info on the subject.

> what  is the best way round so I don't need to use threads

This question is not appropriate for SO (too broad)